# Ability to pin a Chrome tab group?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome has recently introduced this great tab group feature.

However, I am still trying to find out how to pin an entire tab group so that it keeps its primary position and doesn't get pushed to the right edges whenever I open new groups.

Does anyone have a solution to that?

Comment: Anything pinned always gets placed on the left and groups cannot be pinned. What I usually do is create a new tab on the right outside of the group and turn that into a group itself. Also, a group will always be placed right of a pinned tab. So I have a dedicated group with my pinned tabs now.

Comment: @LPChip The problem with tab groups and pinned tabs is that links that open in a new tab from a pinned tab will always open to the left of any existing tab groups. For example, I have always GMail open as the first pinned tab, so when I open a link from a mail, it will open to the left of my tab groups and move them to the right. This is really annoying.

Comment: No solution, but I would also like to have such an ability!

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1495103

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try the feature group tab save. Although you cannot pin the tab group, you can reopen the saved group tab.

To turn on by this:

```
chrome://flags/#tab-groups-save
```

Comment: Hello, that doesn't add anything new to the question. They asked specifically for a way to pin the group, they know the feature exists.